# Why would a one year old suddenly refuse solid foods

Tags: infant, eating, solids

My one year old daughter has suddenly refused any solid food that is wet or sticky. She will only eat things like bread or cereals with an exception for puree. She weas eating a bit of everything up untill the past few days. We have ruled out teething for the most part, we don't feel any on their way. Is this a phase?

Comment: Not an answer, but try offering her a spoon and see if she's more inclined to attempt the sticky/wet stuff.  Sometimes kids just need things shaken up a bit.

Comment: @MegCoates, we tried that and all she did was pick the food up with her hands, place it on the spoon and then put it on the plate. Very cute but wan't quite the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly, since children at that age change their preferences constantly.  My son has been running hot and cold on (eg.) avocados ever since he started eating solids: sometimes they're the best thing in the world, but -- usually after eating them often for a while -- he seems to get bored and refuses to touch them.  We pause for a while, try again later, and boom, they're gold again.

So don't worry about it too much, just offer her various foods and see what she decides to like that day.  And if you're concerned that "wet" or "sticky" is the problem, I have a hard time imagining she'll refuse eg. ice cream or a spoonful of jam!